# Making a select that sends form automatically and opens another select (CodeIgniter)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am pretty new to CodeIgniter and php and I know little about javascript.

I am trying to make a select that sends automatically the form when you select and option, and then it should display right beneath it another select that has the same automatic functionality and sends you to another page.

Basically first you select the country, then the city select is displayed, you select a city and you're sent the city page.

Comment: check this http://mikeheavers.com/main/code-item/dynamic_dependent_dropdown_filtering_with_codeigniter_and_jquery

Comment: @mazraara - I guess that is _exactly_ what he needs, learn by copying!

Comment: I have tried to follow that tutorial and adapt it to my web, but it doesn't work. I don't get how the jquery function communicates with the form and the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to do it, I have barely any idea about javascript, jQuery and AJAX, so I came out with this simplicity and it works:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var pais_id = $('#paises').val();
        if (pais_id == '0') // selección por defecto
        {
                $('#ciudades').show().hide();
        }

        $('#paises').change(function() {
                if (pais_id != "")
                {
                        $('#ciudades').show();
                }
                else
                {
                        $('#ciudades').show().hide();
                }
        });
 });
```

Then I control with php what I have to load in each select and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for something like Chained Select, which is not specifically CodeIgniter, but a  jQuery plugin:

See the demo here: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained/demo.html

And the plugin page here: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained